# Does the Ubuntu installer create a hybrid MBR partition table on EFI systems?

Tags: boot, uefi, mbr

I have a MacBook Air that previously ran Fedora with a dual-boot Windows side for a few engineering tools. I recently switched back to Ubuntu, installing Ubuntu over Fedora using the same EFI boot partition and primary `/` partition. Somehow in this process, Windows started failing to boot (error code 0xc0000001 or just getting stuck on the Windows logo).

After a lot of troubleshooting, I discovered that my disk had a hybrid MBR partition table (it's a GPT disk) that was confusing both the Windows installer and, apparently, something in the Windows boot process. Unfortunately, I don't know if this hybrid MBR existed before I installed Ubuntu or not.

I used `gdisk` to delete the hybrid MBR and replace it with a protective MBR. Now everything boots correctly again.

*My question is: what did the Ubuntu installer do that caused Windows to be unable to boot? Does it transparently add a hybrid MBR to improve compatibility?*

(By the way, this is just out of curiosity. Everything is working great again thanks to `gdisk`.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although a year later, I'd like to share my findings about Ubuntu and disk partitioning. I have been playing with Linux Mint 18 (that just came out). It is based on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed it by letting it use all disk space automatically. **Please, note that I am doing it on an iMac 2009 which has some soft of EFI bios**. After the installation I ran `gdisk -l /dev/sda` and it said:

> MBR: hybrid
>  BSD: not present
>  APM: not present
>  GPT:
>   present

On the other hand, as an experiment, I tried manually partitioning the disk by creating protective MBR and then installing. The installation went just fine and it boots with no problems. So, it seems that Hybrid MBR is not mandatory.

I read this post about the dangers of Hybrid MBR: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html I have no idea why the installer creates `MBR: hybrid` when it should be avoided.